# Combinations of digits in a URL

Tags: python, url, python-requests, permutation

I'm currently trying to iterate over all combinations of 4 digits on a URL but it seems to be only doing a handful of them (instead of 10,000). Any ideas why?

```
import requests 
from itertools import combinations

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

for c in combinations(x, 4):
    print(c) 
    URL = "http://www.google.com/" + str(c)
    r = requests.get(url = URL) 
    print(r.content)
```

It only does the following permutations:
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 6)
(1, 2, 3, 7)
(1, 2, 3, 8)
(1, 2, 3, 9)
(1, 2, 3, 0)
(1, 2, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 6)
(1, 2, 4, 7)
(1, 2, 4, 8)
(1, 2, 4, 9)
(1, 2, 4, 0)
(1, 2, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 5, 8)
(1, 2, 5, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 0)
(1, 2, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 6, 8)
(1, 2, 6, 9)
(1, 2, 6, 0)
(1, 2, 7, 8)
(1, 2, 7, 9)
(1, 2, 7, 0)
(1, 2, 8, 9)
(1, 2, 8, 0)
(1, 2, 9, 0)
(1, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 3, 4, 6)
(1, 3, 4, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 8)
(1, 3, 4, 9)
(1, 3, 4, 0)
(1, 3, 5, 6)
(1, 3, 5, 7)
(1, 3, 5, 8)
(1, 3, 5, 9)
(1, 3, 5, 0)
(1, 3, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 6, 8)
(1, 3, 6, 9)
(1, 3, 6, 0)
(1, 3, 7, 8)
(1, 3, 7, 9)
(1, 3, 7, 0)
(1, 3, 8, 9)
(1, 3, 8, 0)
(1, 3, 9, 0)
(1, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 4, 5, 8)
(1, 4, 5, 9)
(1, 4, 5, 0)
(1, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 4, 6, 8)
(1, 4, 6, 9)
(1, 4, 6, 0)
(1, 4, 7, 8)
(1, 4, 7, 9)
(1, 4, 7, 0)
(1, 4, 8, 9)
(1, 4, 8, 0)
(1, 4, 9, 0)
(1, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 5, 6, 8)
(1, 5, 6, 9)
(1, 5, 6, 0)
(1, 5, 7, 8)
(1, 5, 7, 9)
(1, 5, 7, 0)
(1, 5, 8, 9)
(1, 5, 8, 0)
(1, 5, 9, 0)
(1, 6, 7, 8)
(1, 6, 7, 9)
(1, 6, 7, 0)
(1, 6, 8, 9)
(1, 6, 8, 0)
(1, 6, 9, 0)
(1, 7, 8, 9)
(1, 7, 8, 0)
(1, 7, 9, 0)
(1, 8, 9, 0)
(2, 3, 4, 5)
(2, 3, 4, 6)
(2, 3, 4, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 8)
(2, 3, 4, 9)
(2, 3, 4, 0)
(2, 3, 5, 6)
(2, 3, 5, 7)
(2, 3, 5, 8)
(2, 3, 5, 9)
(2, 3, 5, 0)
(2, 3, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 6, 8)
(2, 3, 6, 9)
(2, 3, 6, 0)
(2, 3, 7, 8)
(2, 3, 7, 9)
(2, 3, 7, 0)
(2, 3, 8, 9)
(2, 3, 8, 0)
(2, 3, 9, 0)
(2, 4, 5, 6)
(2, 4, 5, 7)
(2, 4, 5, 8)
(2, 4, 5, 9)
(2, 4, 5, 0)
(2, 4, 6, 7)
(2, 4, 6, 8)
(2, 4, 6, 9)
(2, 4, 6, 0)
(2, 4, 7, 8)
(2, 4, 7, 9)
(2, 4, 7, 0)
(2, 4, 8, 9)
(2, 4, 8, 0)
(2, 4, 9, 0)
(2, 5, 6, 7)
(2, 5, 6, 8)
(2, 5, 6, 9)
(2, 5, 6, 0)
(2, 5, 7, 8)
(2, 5, 7, 9)
(2, 5, 7, 0)
(2, 5, 8, 9)
(2, 5, 8, 0)
(2, 5, 9, 0)
(2, 6, 7, 8)
(2, 6, 7, 9)
(2, 6, 7, 0)
(2, 6, 8, 9)
(2, 6, 8, 0)
(2, 6, 9, 0)
(2, 7, 8, 9)
(2, 7, 8, 0)
(2, 7, 9, 0)
(2, 8, 9, 0)
(3, 4, 5, 6)
(3, 4, 5, 7)
(3, 4, 5, 8)
(3, 4, 5, 9)
(3, 4, 5, 0)
(3, 4, 6, 7)
(3, 4, 6, 8)
(3, 4, 6, 9)
(3, 4, 6, 0)
(3, 4, 7, 8)
(3, 4, 7, 9)
(3, 4, 7, 0)
(3, 4, 8, 9)
(3, 4, 8, 0)
(3, 4, 9, 0)
(3, 5, 6, 7)
(3, 5, 6, 8)
(3, 5, 6, 9)
(3, 5, 6, 0)
(3, 5, 7, 8)
(3, 5, 7, 9)
(3, 5, 7, 0)
(3, 5, 8, 9)
(3, 5, 8, 0)
(3, 5, 9, 0)
(3, 6, 7, 8)
(3, 6, 7, 9)
(3, 6, 7, 0)
(3, 6, 8, 9)
(3, 6, 8, 0)
(3, 6, 9, 0)
(3, 7, 8, 9)
(3, 7, 8, 0)
(3, 7, 9, 0)
(3, 8, 9, 0)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
(4, 5, 6, 8)
(4, 5, 6, 9)
(4, 5, 6, 0)
(4, 5, 7, 8)
(4, 5, 7, 9)
(4, 5, 7, 0)
(4, 5, 8, 9)
(4, 5, 8, 0)
(4, 5, 9, 0)
(4, 6, 7, 8)
(4, 6, 7, 9)
(4, 6, 7, 0)
(4, 6, 8, 9)
(4, 6, 8, 0)
(4, 6, 9, 0)
(4, 7, 8, 9)
(4, 7, 8, 0)
(4, 7, 9, 0)
(4, 8, 9, 0)
(5, 6, 7, 8)
(5, 6, 7, 9)
(5, 6, 7, 0)
(5, 6, 8, 9)
(5, 6, 8, 0)
(5, 6, 9, 0)
(5, 7, 8, 9)
(5, 7, 8, 0)
(5, 7, 9, 0)
(5, 8, 9, 0)
(6, 7, 8, 9)
(6, 7, 8, 0)
(6, 7, 9, 0)
(6, 8, 9, 0)
(7, 8, 9, 0)

Thanks!

Comment: 10C4 without repetitions is 210. That's why it does 210.

Answer (score 1):

Combination is ordered, you can easily see what it produces if you reduce the input:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]

for c in combinations(x, 2):
    print(c)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)  (1, 3)  (1, 4)   # all combinations of 1 and any other number
(2, 3)  (2, 4)           # (1,2) was already done, so not repeated
(3, 4)                   # (1,3) and (2,3) already done, so not repeated
```

You find more details in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

There is also no reason to do itertools.combinations at all.

Use  `for c in range(1000,10000):` instead. This will create all numbers from 1000 up to 9999